# Backstretch jQuery dot navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, jquery-backstretch

I am trying to build navigation for a backstretch slider using dots.

Currently I am using the value of the dot to change to the slide with that value on click.

Letting it autoplay 1 or 2 slides and the clicking on the first dot the index returns 01 instead of 0. This then breaks the autoplaying slider as well as the navigation.

I can't seem to find any fixes after googling, any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".slider").backstretch([
 "http://lw.dev.plx.mk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/iStock_000015135168Large.jpg",
 "http://lw.dev.plx.mk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/IMG_2961.jpg",
 "http://lw.dev.plx.mk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Global-Legend-White-conservatory-1-bespoke-external.jpg",
 "http://lw.dev.plx.mk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Buckley-3.jpg",  ],{
  duration:3000,
  fade:750,
 });
 $('#dot-0').addClass('selected');

 $('.dot').click(function() {
     $('.slider').backstretch("show", ($(this).attr('value')));
     console.log('Value - ' + ($(this).attr('value')));
     $('.dot').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
 });

 $('.slider').on("backstretch.before", function (e, instance, index) {
  console.log('Index - ' + index);
  var currentSlide = $('#dot-' + index);
  $('.dot').removeClass('selected');
  $(currentSlide).addClass('selected');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" style="position: relative; z-index: 0; background: none;">
  <div class="slider-dots">
   <div class="dot" id="dot-0" value="0">x</div>
   <div class="dot" id="dot-1" value="1">x</div>
   <div class="dot" id="dot-2" value="2">x</div>
   <div class="dot" id="dot-3" value="3">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $('.dot').first().addClass('selected');
 
 var instance = $(".slider").data("backstretch");
 $('.dot').click(function () {
   var index = $('.dot').index( $(this) );
   $('.dot').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   instance.show(index);
   return false;
 });
 
 $('.slider').on("backstretch.before", function (e, instance, index) {
  var currentSlide = $('#dot-' + index);
  $('.dot').removeClass('selected');
  $(currentSlide).addClass('selected');
 });
```

Fixed with the code above